# Inserting into one table data from another table in BigQuery. I'm trying to insert data into table 1 from table 2

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
INSERT INTO 'project.dataset.table1' (column_one, column_two, column_three)
    SELECT 
        column_one,
        column_two,
        column_three
    FROM
        'project.dataset.table2'
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Inserted row has wrong column count; Has 4, expected 3 at [6:1].

The error is in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the singlequote ' with backtick ` for project.dataset.table1 and project.dataset.table2? And can you share the error message when you tried the posted answer of @HemangA?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove single quotes and try below

INSERT INTO project.dataset.table1 (column_one, column_two, column_three)
SELECT
column_one,
column_two,
column_three
FROM
project.dataset.table2

Comment: Hello, that didn't work for me in BigQuery